# HTML::image() rendering img tag not image laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to display image with `{{ HTML::image('images/login_user.png') }}` but it gives the output as `<img src="http://myproject/images/login_user.png">` not image. I have put image into /public/images folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double curly braces in blade templating will output the string and it will not parse as tag.

use

e.g

```
 {!! HTML::image('images/login_user.png') !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

{{ something }} - this in laravel 5+, will escape anything and output only string, it is done to protect user from all kind source of injection.

{!! something !!}} - Use this in your case such as {!! HTML::image('images/login_user.png') !!}